# Blazor WebAssembly SEO

Tags: seo

I have made an online store with Blazor Client(WebAssembly).

With the client, I get all the products correctly and everything works perfectly. It looks like magic.

I was thinking that when the day comes to make the jump to production, there would be an easy way to convert the code to HTML or something like that that can be read by a search engine. However, I haven't managed to get something really functional.

Comment: Your question on SO should not have been closed.  Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71217380/60761

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking, but it appears you received an answer over at Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71217380/can-i-start-app-using-blazor-server-then-load-webassembly) and the question is still open there, so it's being closed here.